# Prove Bernoulli's inequality

Tags: induction

Using the proposition I have checked it for a($1$)
$1+x=1+x$ so a($1$) is true
A($n$)=$(1+x)^n\ge 1+nx$ assuming this is right according to inductive hypothesis
Considering a($n+1$)
$( 1+x)^n+1\ge 1+(n+1)x$....($1$)
Now
$(1+x)^n+1\ge (1+nx)(x+1)$...
$(1+x)^{n+1}\ge 1+x(n+1)+nx^2$....($2$)
Considering the equation $1$ and $2$
$1+(n+1)x\ge 1+x(n+1)+nx^2\le (1+x)^n+1$ as $nx^2$ is a positive quantity..so the proposition is true...but is the proposition is true if we take $n<0$?

Comment: Have you heard of Bernoulli's inequalities?

Comment: I know this is Bernoulli's inequality...but I am confused

Comment: Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score 1):

we have to prove that $$ (1+x)^{n+1}\geq 1+(n+1)x$$
multiplying $$(1+x)^n\geq 1+nx$$ by $1+x>0$ we get
$$(1+x)^{n+1}\geq (1+nx)(1+x)=1+x(n+1)+nx^2$$ and this is greater than $$1+(n+1)x$$

Comment: But what if we take n<0..in that case 1+(n+1)x>=1+(n+1)x+nx^2

Comment: Does your post answer the question:"$\texttt{...but is the proposition is true if we take $n<0$? }$" ?

Comment: Is this proposition true for n<0

Comment: Yes........callculus

Comment: @Akulsharma Is your question answered ? If yes, you can check the answer.

Comment: @callculus...the answer given here I already know...but I am expecting different answer...if the proposition holds true for n<0

Comment: @Akulsharma So my intuition was right. I´m wondering about people who vote up without reading/understanding the question and the answer.

Comment: I would be glad if you can give answer of my question..

Comment: see here for the other cases https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli%27s_inequality

Comment: That's what I was thinking...anyways thanks for the help sir..