# $(1+\frac{1}{3})^n \ge 1+\frac{n}{3}$, $\forall n\geq 0$ proof by induction

Tags: proof-explanation, induction

How can I prove this by induction?
[Here's the question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nLemt.png)

Step 1 ) for $n = 0$ both it's true
Step 2 ) for $n= k$ assume that $\textstyle\displaystyle{(1+\frac{1}3)^k\geq 1 + \frac{k}{3}}$ is true
Step 3 ) prove that for $n = k+1$, $\textstyle\displaystyle{(1+\frac{1}3)^k+1$ \geq 1 + \frac{k+1}{3}}$ is true
I started with the left side $(1+\frac{1}3)^{k+1}$ = $(1+\frac{1}3)^k(1+\frac{1}3)$
then I replaced $\textstyle\displaystyle{(1+\frac{1}{3})^k}$ with my assumption $\textstyle\displaystyle{1 + \frac{k}{3}}$ so now it's $\textstyle\displaystyle{(1+\frac{1}3)^k(1+\frac{1}3)\geq (k+\frac{1}3)(1+\frac{1}3)}$

**What should I do next ?**

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: @Seba Welcome to Math SE. Cf. [Bernoulli's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli%27s_inequality).

Comment: You're pretty much done if you can show $\left(1 + \frac{k}{3}\right)\left(1 + \frac{1}{3}\right) \ge 1 + \frac{k + 1}{3}$. Try expanding the left hand side, and see if any terms cancel on the right.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos thanks for the advice

Comment: @TheoBendit can you explain more

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Proof by induction of Bernoulli's inequality: $(1 + x)^n \geq 1 + nx$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/475309/proof-by-induction-of-bernoullis-inequality-1-xn-geq-1-nx). There are quite a few other similar induction proof questions here, e.g., [Bernoullis inequality proof](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1421505), [Bernoulli's inequality by induction](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/649025) and [Prove Bernoulli's inequality](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2421572).

Comment: @Seba I mean just expand the brackets on the left hand side. I could tell you what it is, but I'd rather guide you to do it for yourself. What do you get when you expand $\left(1 + \frac{k}{3}\right)\left(1 + \frac{1}{3}\right)$?

Comment: @TheoBendit 1+ 1/3 + (4k / 9 )

Comment: @Seba Can't argue with that! I was thinking more as presenting it unsimplified as a sum of four terms, i.e. $1 + \frac{1}{3} + \frac{k}{3} + \frac{k}{9}$. Compare to the right hand side: $1 + \frac{k + 1}{3}$. What do you notice on that's on the left hand side that isn't on the right hand side? Is there anything on the right hand side that isn't on the left hand side? Another way of thinking about it: take the difference $1 + \frac{1}{3} + \frac{4k}{9} - \left(1 + \frac{k+1}{3}\right)$. What is the difference, once fully simplified? Is it $\ge 0$?

Comment: @TheoBendit if I take the difference it will be 1/3 +(k-3) / 9 and in the assumption k >=0 so in this way, I'm done ??

Comment: @TheoBendit or if I want to compare the right hand side is now 1+(k+1)/3 +k/9 so it will be definitely bigger than  1+(k+1)/3 which is the right hand side is this what you mean ??

Comment: @Seba Yes, either line of reasoning will work. Either which way, you've proven the given inequality.

Comment: @TheoBendit thanks for everything it's actually the first time I feel like someone is trying to explain it to me step by step.

Comment: @Seba No worries. To be fair, step-by-step is tricky in Q&A format. Glad I could help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set $P(n): (1+\frac 13)^n\geq 1+\frac n3, n\in \Bbb N$. We see that $P(1): \frac 43\geq \frac 43$ is true. Suppose that $P(n)$ holds for some $n\in \Bbb N$. Then $(1+\frac 13)^{n+1}=(1+\frac 13)^n(1+\frac 13)\geq (1+\frac n3)(1+\frac13)=1+\frac13 +\frac n3 +\frac n6=1+(\frac 13 +\frac n3)+\frac n6\geq 1+\frac 13 (n+1): P(n+1).$

q.e.d.